# Polar-transform image in R

Tags: r, image-processing, transformation, polar-coordinates, atan2

I am trying to transform an image (represented as a matrix) in R, into polar coordinate space with the origin being 0,0 (top left corner). Given the `215x215` matrix `x` which looks like:

[image]

```
x0 = as.vector(col(x))
y0 = as.vector(row(x))

r = sqrt( (x0^2) + (y0^2)  )#x
a = atan(y0/x0)#y
m = as.matrix(data.frame(y=a, x=r))

m = round(m)
m[m>215] = NA
m[m==0] = NA

xn = x[m]
xn = matrix(xn, 215, 215)
```

However, xn just looks like:

[image]

When I expect this:

[image]

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a problem with the angle: `atan` returns an angle in radians.
if you round it, there is not much information left...

Try with:

```
a = atan(y0/x0) * 215 / (pi/2)
```

[image: Transformed image]

It is not the image you expect, which is apparently the inverse transformation, 
with the center in the middle of the image.

```
# Load the image
library(png)
library(RCurl)
d <- readPNG( getBinaryURL( "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMR3C.png" ) )
image(d, col=gray(0:255/255))

# Origin for the polar coordinates
x0 <- ncol(d)/2
y0 <- nrow(d)/2

# The value of pixel (i,j) in the final image 
# comes from the pixel, in the original image, 
# with polar coordinates (r[i],theta[i]).
# We need a grid for the values of r and theta.
r <- 1:ceiling(sqrt( max(x0,nrow(d))^2 + max(y0,ncol(d))^2))
theta <- -pi/2 + seq(0,2*pi, length = 200)
r_theta <- expand.grid(r=r, theta=theta)

# Convert those polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates:
x <- with( r_theta, x0 + r * cos(theta) )
y <- with( r_theta, y0 + r * sin(theta) )
# Truncate them
x <- pmin( pmax( x, 1 ), ncol(d) )
y <- pmin( pmax( y, 1 ), nrow(d) )

# Build an empty matrix with the desired size and populate it
r <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(r), ncol=length(theta))
r[] <- d[cbind(x,y)]
image(r, col=gray(0:255/255))
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Could you maybe explain what each part of the code is doing? I'm a little confused as to the formula you are using for r and theta and the multiplication of sin/cos values. Thanks again

Comment: I have somewhat simplified the code and added a few comments.